# Problema con Métodos en Java (No puedo usarlos)

Tags: java, poo, switch

El programa en cuestión es sobre un taller mecánico en el cual entrar tanto automóviles como motos este programa debe registrar cada vehículo que ingrese al taller y en base a el arreglo que necesite calcular el coste del mismo

Mi problema es que a la hora de querer usar los métodos de los cálculos en la main del programa no me deja usarlos y la verdad no llego a entender que me falta o que estoy obviando

Adjunto los códigos del paquete a continuación:

PD: La verdad que no soy del todo diestro con java así que agradecería sus consejos

Y acá están las consignas claves del problema la clase vehículo es abstracta y deberá heredarse a las clase automóvil y moto

Con lo del calculo y los casos de reparación era libre así que solo cree 3 tipos de reparaciones

Y por ultimo en las salidas de los casos del switch dice cantidad de días y de arreglos a realizar
En esos cálculos me falta agregar los días y el numero de arreglos como variables pero no se como pedirlas al usuario
Es un dato menor que no debería conflictuarlos a la hora de
ayudarme

Sin mas nada que agregar les agradezco de antemano su atención

1)_

```
    public abstract class vehiculo {//Clase abstracta
    //Atributos
    String marca;
    String modelo;
    int patente;    
    
    //Constructor
    public vehiculo(String marca,String modelo,int patente) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.patente = patente;
    }
    //Metodos
    public String obtenerMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    public String obtenerModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }
    public int obtenerPatente() {
        return patente;
    }
    
    
}
```

2)_

```
    public class automovil extends vehiculo{
    //Atributos 
    String Tipoauto;
    int Cantpuertas;
    
    //Contructor
    public automovil (String marca ,String modelo ,int patente,String Tipoauto ,int Cantpuertas) {
        super(marca,modelo,patente);
        this.Cantpuertas = Cantpuertas;
        this.Tipoauto = Tipoauto;
    }
    public int obtenerPuertas(){
        return Cantpuertas;
    }
    public String Tipoauto() {
        return Tipoauto;
    }
}
```

3)_

```
public class moto extends vehiculo{
    //Atributo 
    int cilindrada;
    
    //Contructor
    public moto(String marca , String modelo ,int patente ,int cilindrada){
        super(marca,modelo,patente);
        this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
    }
    //Metodos
    public int obtenerCilindrada() {
        return cilindrada;
    }
}
```

4)_

```
public class Logica {
    //Atributos
    int luces = 40;//Precio repuesto
    int ruedas = 50;
    int aboyaduras = 30;//Chapa y pintura
    float ganancia ;// = 10%
    int costosest = 130;//Por dia
    float total;
    float resultado;
    
    //Contructor
    
    public Logica(int luces , int ruedas ,int aboyaduras,float ganancia , float total , float resultado,int costosest){
        
        this.aboyaduras = aboyaduras;
        this.costosest = costosest;
        this.ganancia = ganancia;
        this.ruedas = ruedas;
        this.luces = luces;
        this.total = total;
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }
    
        //Calculo y Metodos
    
    public float lucesCalculo() {
        total = luces + costosest;  
        ganancia = total*100/10;//10%   
        resultado = total + ganancia;
        
            return resultado;
        }
    public float ruedasCalculo() {
        total = ruedas + costosest; 
        ganancia = total*100/10;//10%   
        resultado = total + ganancia;
        
            return resultado;
        }
    public float aboyadurasCalculo() {
        total = aboyaduras + costosest; 
        ganancia = total*100/10;//10%   
        resultado = total + ganancia;
        
            return resultado;
        }
            
    }
```

5)_

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Principal {
    
        public static void main(String[]args){
            int opcion = 0;
            
        Principal ruedas = new Principal(); 
        Principal luces = new Principal();
        Principal aboyaduras = new Principal();
            
            
            
            System.out.println("Bienvenido a la aplicacion de su taller mecanico\n");
            System.out.println("Ingrese el problema del vehiculo: \n");
            
            while(opcion<4) {
                opcion++;
                
                Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese 1 para ruedas pinchadas , Ingrese 2 para luces rotas , Ingrese 3 para aboyaduras"));
                
                switch(opcion) {
                    
                case 1: 
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de ruedas a reponer y dias a emplear :");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de luces a reponer y dias a emplear:");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de aboyaduras a reparar y dias a emplear :");
            
                case 4:
                    break;
                }
            
        } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Tienes una pregunta con un titulo muuuuyyy parecido, trata de mejorar la redacción del titulo describiendo mejor el problema que tienes.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema y dónde exactamente? Si hay algún mensaje de error agrégalo también a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Mi problema es que no puedo mandar a llamar a los metodos que hice y no tengo idea si estoy obviando algo o se me paso algo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenass, segun lo que vi te falta el scanner a fin de introducir por teclado el trabajo que se realizara seria algo asi
Scaneer a = new Scanner(System.in);
opcion=a.nexInt();
Lo mismo pasa en el switch pides datos pero no los almacenas en ninguna variable. Tambien te falta llamar a tus metodos para que te calculen lo que pides

```
switch(opcion) {
                
     case 1: 
           System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de ruedas a reponer y dias a emplear :");
           int cantruedas= a.nextInt();
           int dias=a.nextInt(); 
           int result= ruedascalculo();
           break;
```

Deberias agregar una varible al comienzo de tu ciclo while
Ej:

```
int recorrer=0;
```

a fin de evitar confusiones con los nombres

Espero te sirva de algo

Comment: Buenas en parte si me ayudo el tema de el new Scanner pero Tenes idea de porque no puedo llamar a los métodos desde el main eso es lo que me esta conflictuando mas que otra cosa

Answer (score 4):

No puedes por que el main es estático, y para poder llamar a un contexto no estático tienes que instanciar la clase.

```
Logica logica = new Logica(....);
logica.lucesCalculo();
```